# Find an image inside of a video using python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I was wondering if I am going about this the right way, or if there is a way that is much more efficient.

I am trying to look for an image inside of a video, like on every single frame of the video this image might be contained somewhere inside of it (its not the full size frame, just a small one).

Currently pulling the video into pictures as such:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('My_Video.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  print ('Read a new frame: ', success)
  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
  count += 1
```

Then looping through them all as such:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_rgb = cv2.imread('frame1.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('small_icon_I_am_looking_for.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

Is there a way to perhaps skip the saving of the pictures? I am doing this across thousands of hours of video, and saving and deleting every frame I feel will use a ton of time that might not be needed. Any ideas how I can search for this without needing to save the picture each time? This is an example of what I mean, say there was a video of super mario being played, it looks for this coin:

[image: Coin]

and detects it as such:

[image: Coin detected]

This currently works, but just looking for a better way.

Comment: Could you not process the images as you read them? Or do you mean avoid the saving of the mini frames in the second part?

Comment: I mean in the first part, just couldn't figure out how to do it. Do you know how, I have not worked with this sort of code much and this was the best I could do.

Comment: Answer added but I may have misunderstood you. Let me know in the comments.

Comment: This will also save every single frame which might kill your computer's memory. Maybe you can add a condition to only save frames if the value is found? Depends what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I haven't misunderstood you, the below should work. On the whole your code is well written with just minimum changes needed to do what you are asking. There was also an issue with you discarding the first frame because of the structure of your while loop. A good way to avoid this is the loop and a half/while True construct:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process_image(img_rgb, template, count):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    w, h = template.shape[::-1]

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.8
    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

    # This will write different res.png for each frame. Change this as you require
    cv2.imwrite('res{0}.png'.format(count),img_rgb)   


def main():
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('My_Video.mp4')
    template = cv2.imread('small_icon_I_am_looking_for.png',0)  # open template only once
    count = 0
    while True:
      success,image = vidcap.read()
      if not success: break         # loop and a half construct is useful
      print ('Read a new frame: ', success)
      process_image(image, template, count)
      count += 1
```

Comment: Have not tested yet, but this looks exactly what I was looking for. Hopefully this runs much faster. Fantastic work:)

Comment: @Lain Seems like a cool program! Let me know if this doesn't work or is still slow; we can try optimising it more.

Comment: I certainly need to modify it more. Ideally it need to only check every like 100th frame (since I am detecting an icon on a load screen). After it find the icon it can skip like 20 min of video too. Ill do my best to modify without bothering you though.

Comment: Is there a way to skip the reading of frames in main? Currently have it calling process image every 100th frame, but vidcap.read() just reads the next frame, can I tell it to read like... 100 frames from now for example? Its still much to slow for what I need.

Comment: @Lain The issue is that some video encodings decode the next frame using information from the current frame and so it is difficult to discretize them. According to [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24714/skipping-frames-in-videocapture/) answer, you can apparently skip frames with `vidcap.grab()`  but I am not too sure about this. Give it a try! Do you have a github repository with the files? I can try seeing where the code is running slow.